# How to have a field disabled for a form when just displaying data, but enabled when using the new form to input data

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a single form that is used for either displaying data in read only format, and you get to this by clicking on a record in the table and are taken to a read only detail view.

I also want to reuse the same form as a way to input data into the table - by default I have all the fields disabled for my read only view and so would like to find a way to override this when generating the form for my insert view?

I thought if I wrapped the form in a POST method in my template, it would somehow enable the fields but doesn't seem to work

forms.py

```py
from django import forms

class BusinessDataForm(forms.Form):
    tableName = forms.CharField(strip=True, empty_value='NULL', disabled=True)
```

views.py

```py
# Django imports
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Local imports
from .forms import BusinessDataForm
from .tables import ResultsTable as rt
import common.dbConnectionManager as dbc

# System imports
import sys
import pyodbc
sys.path.insert(0,'..')
pyodbc.pooling = False


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def db_display(request):
    dbo = dbc.dbConnectionManager()
    query_result_as_dict = dbo.run_query('SELECT TOP 10 DataBaseName, TableName, Version, TableKind, CreatorName FROM DBC.TABLESV;')
    dbo.disconnect()

    table = rt(query_result_as_dict)

    #tables.RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, "db_display.html", {"table" : table})

def business_data_display(request, table_name):
    dbo = dbc.dbConnectionManager()
    query_result_as_dict = dbo.run_query('''SELECT DataBaseName, 
                                            TableName,
                                            Version,
                                            TableKind,
                                            CreatorName 
                                            FROM DBC.TABLESV 
                                            where TableName = '{table_name}' '''.format(table_name=table_name))

    form = BusinessDataForm(initial={'tableName' : query_result_as_dict[0]['TableName']})

    return render(request, 'business_data_form.html', {'form' : form})

def business_data_new(request):
    form = BusinessDataForm()
    return render(request, 'business_data_new.html', {'form' : form})
```

business_data_new.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

So far the field remains disabled no matter what, any ideas how to override it? Can it be done when I instantiate `BusinessDataForm()` in my views.py?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this by adding the following before passing my form to the template

`form.fields['tableName'].disabled = False`